# xpath troubles assigning style to a tag which contains not attribute but another tag before closing

Tags: php, dom, xpath

**Hello everybody!**

I am student in 1 course and am trying to create something. I have been trying to change the style of '<'li'>' which contains a '<'span'>' tag and the rest '<'li'>' tags should remain as it is. this is how, i have gone so far:

```
<?php
$html = <<< HTML
<ul>
    <li><span style="font-weight:bold;color:white;">foo</span></li>
    <li style="color: brown;"><a href="#bar">bar span</a></li>
    <li><span><a href="#baz">baz</a></span></li>
</ul>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('//li[not(@style)]/span[not(@style)]') as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold; background:black;');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0)); 

?>
```

**So this results in:**

```
<ul>
<li><span style="font-weight:bold;color:white;">foo</span></li>
    <li style="color: brown;"><a href="#bar">bar span</a></li>
    <li><span style="font-weight:bold; background:black;"><a href="#baz">baz</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

**What i need to achieve is this:**

```
<ul>
<li><span style="font-weight:bold;color:white;">foo</span></li>
    <li style="color: brown;"><a href="#bar">bar span</a></li>
    <li style="font-weight:bold; background:black;"><span><a href="#baz">baz</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

so i want to style the li and not the span!

Please help a learner, just tried a lot and cant find the way around.

Is this a correct way???

```
<?php
$url ='http://3d.te.ua/xpath/ria.html';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('//li[not(@style)]/span[not(@style)]') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold; background:black;');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0)); 

?>
```

Comment: You normally use CSS for that, not xpath: `li {font-weight:bold; color:white;}` - using `style` attributes is also very bad practice. So two reasons to not do it that way. If it's for learning xpath, that might be something differnt. So just feel reminded if that is the case.

Comment: Actually the answer given hek2mgl is correct, thats what i wanted to do. If i style li directly than all the li will get that attribute but i needed to style the li tags which has span tags in them. Thank you for interest and appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, there is no parent selector in CSS, probably use the XPath then to add a class to that tag so that you can then with CSS. You should prevent the use of `style` attributes, there most often is a better alternative. (and sure hek2gl's answer is correct, didn't say that xpath won't work only that you should consider to not use inlines styles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/..` to select the parent node:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('//li[not(@style)]/span[not(@style)]/..') as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:bold; background:black;');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul')->item(0));
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply! but it styles the span tag and I need to style the LI tag. Please help. I appreciate your interest.

Comment: .. and even better! :D check my update. This is more *the xpath way*.

Comment: check the last part of my question